# Assistence clearing up Angular 2 Component Test Tutorial

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to learn Angular's API for testing. I am currently reading the following tutorial:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#atu-apis

My understanding of how the following code works is not in line with what I am seeing while I am running the tests. As I understand the code, the second it method is reseting the elements content to 'Test Title' and checking for equality in the toContain method.

```
it('should display original title', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
});

it('should display a different test title', () => {
  comp.title = 'Test Title';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.textContent).toContain('Test Title');
});
```

However when I play around with the code and make the following change from toContain('Test Title'); to toContain('Test'), the test still passes. This can be seen in the live example:

https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/testing/ts/banner-inline-specs.eplnkr.html

[image]

I get the same results in my own tests. I am assuming the test should fail but it does not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because as you can see in the [Jasmine's Default Matcher's](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers#jasmines-default-matchers) you're not using the right one. Try changing `.toContain` with `.toEqual` :)

What `.toContain` does is check if what you're searching is SOMEWHERE there.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that.

Comment: Glad could help.